# app.configに不正な値を設定した場合の挙動について

Tags: c#

タイトルの件、app.config（*exe.config）に型付きの値（settings）を設定後、*exe.configに不正な値を設定した場合、どのような値が設定値として取得できますか？

以下の場合の動きがしりたいです。
1.型の異なる値を設定（例えばint型で定義したのに英文字を設定）
→取得に失敗して2と同じになりますか？
2.項目値を削除
→取得出来なかった場合、デフォルト値（settingsに書かれた値）になりますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一応XMLとして有効な範囲で編集された場合は、ご質問のようにデフォルト値になるでしょう。

プログラム・初期configはVisualStudioのIDEで、プロジェクトのプロパティの「設定」タブで定義し、`Properties`の`Settings.Settings`(Settings.Designer.cs)および`app.config`に格納され、ビルドして正常に動作し、*.exe.configだけ編集するものとします。
例としては以下のようになります。

Settings.Designer.cs

```
[global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("99")]
public int Key1 {
    get {
        return ((int)(this["Key1"]));
    }
}
```

app.config

```
<applicationSettings>
  <ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="Key1" serializeAs="String">
      <value>99</value>
    </setting>
  </ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Program.cs

```
Console.WriteLine("Setting Key1 : {0}", Properties.Settings.Default.Key1);
```

---

1.型の異なる値を設定（例えばint型で定義したのに英文字を設定）
→取得に失敗して2と同じになりますか？

答：以下のような範囲の編集ならば、デフォルト値が取得されます。

```
      <value>ZZ等</value>

      <value></value>

      <value />
```

2.項目値を削除
→取得出来なかった場合、デフォルト値（settingsに書かれた値）になりますか？

答：以下のような範囲の編集ならば、デフォルト値が取得されます。
　　以下の部分全体を削除

```
    <setting name="Key1" serializeAs="String">
      <value>99</value>
    </setting>
```

nameの値を定義していないものに変更

```
    <setting name="KeyXX" serializeAs="String">
      <value>99</value>
    </setting>
```

例外：以下のように<value>99</value>の部分を削除すると例外になります。

```
    <setting name="Key1" serializeAs="String">
    </setting>
```

Answer (score 1):

それ以前の問題として、`app.config`がXMLとして不正な状態（閉じタグが一致しない、ファイルが空など）な場合に例外が投げられます。
ですので、質問のような個別のパターンに対応するのではなく、根本的なエラー対策が必要です。